# How to enable git push over SSH in Squid proxy?

Tags: ssh, proxy, git

I have a weird problem. 
I have taken over maintenance (read: hey dumb arse think fast) and setup for some servers accessing the web through a gateway, which utilise Squid proxy.
The users needed to be able to use Git `clone`, `push`, and `pull` via SSH. 
My problem is that `clone` and `pull` works, but push does not. The content of /etc/environment

```
http_proxy=http://SECRET_HOSTNAME:8888/
ftp_proxy=ftp://SECRET_HOSTNAME:8888/
https_proxy=http://SECRET_HOSTNAME:8888/
```

The config for squid is a bit more complex, but I cannot find anything specific to SSH. 
The error I get from git is that repo cannot be reached.

The full output from git on `git push`

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Check that the push uri for the environment is valid, you can have separate push and pull uri links.

Comment: I have just done a pure `git clone` from github. But thanks I will :)

Comment: Same URL @linuxdev2013

Comment: Make sure on the remote repo that that all matches is what I meant.

Comment: I just cloned using HTTPS and there I can push :/

Comment: I do not have problems on other machines with the same repo. Just the once behind this proxy/gateway :)

Comment: and it matches the one of github :)